# Change text depending on what device it's viewed from?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, device, desktop

I have a website. When I go on it with desktops and laptops a piece of text says: *Click Here.*

But when it viewed on mobile I want it to say: *Tap here.*

Is it possible to do this without creating a new site all together for mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: Neither of those are good link text from a UX/accessibility standpoint anyway. Instead, _say what the action will do_, and avoid the whole mess altogether. For example, "Log into your account" or "Cancel your subscription". Imagine coming across those links in isolation, as a screen reader user might. They're completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better you "say what the action will do" as described by one of the comments but to answer your question straight, you can do this with just css media queries:

```css
.mobile {
  display: block;
}
.desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class= 'mobile'>Tap here</p>
<p class= 'desktop'>Click Here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using js:

```js
let newText = ""

function changeText() {
  if (window.innerWidth> 0 && window.innerWidth < 700) {
    newText = "Tap Here!";
  } else if (window.innerWidth > 700) {
    newText = "Click Here!";
  } 
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = newText
 }
```

```html
<body onload="changeText()">
  <p id="text"></p>
 </body>
```

Basically you create a function that runs when the page is loaded, in this functions window.innerWidth return the width of the window, if it is bigger the 700 (px) than the text will be "Click here!" but if the window width is beetwen 0 and 700 the text will be "Tap here!"

Edit: i just saw that in the code snippet it doesn't work, you should try doing it on your own and it will works